# PHP $_FILES does not allow audio files (wav, mp3, aiff etc) to be uploaded - but allows any other type of extension

Tags: javascript, php

## My Problem

---

So I have been trying to create a simple file upload system using **JavaScript** (XHR) and **PHP**, and I have come across a problem where once the file has been uploaded to the **PHP** `handler`, it always returns that `$_FILES` is *not* set.

## Code

---

**JavaScript** (on the server `www.example.com`):

```
var file = document.getElementById("fileInput").files[0];

var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("track", file);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "//handle.example.com/uploads.php", true);

xhr.onload = function(){
    if(xhr.status == 200)
        // awesome, it worked
    else
        return console.error("Something went wrong.");
};
xhr.send(formData);
```

**PHP** (on the server `handle.example.com`):

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example.com", false);

if(isset($_FILES["track"])){
    $file       = $_FILES["track"];
    $fileTemp   = $file["tmp_name"];
    $fileSize   = filesize($fileTemp);

    if($fileSize <= 150000000)
        $data = "Success"; // this is returned if a file is an image file
} else
    $data = "File not set."; // this is returned if a file is an audio file

echo $data;
exit;
```

**HTML** (on the server `www.example.com`):

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="ulF_uF1">
    <input type="file" name="file" accept="audio/x-aiff,audio/flac,audio/mpeg,audio/ogg,audio/wav" id="fileInput">
</form>
```

## What I've Tried

---

- Setting the `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` to `150M` and `151M` respectively.
- Changing the name of the field name
- Changing `$_FILES` to `$_POST`

---

None of this has worked for me, and I can't seem to find another other viable solutions relating to my problem, so all help is appreciated.

## UPDATE:

---

After some careful testing, I realised that my upload script is actually working perfectly. What it doesn't like is the file types that are being uploaded. For some reason, **PHP (version 7.2.1 at least)** does not like when I upload audio files; uploading image files or `PDF`'s work fine.

Comment: what value is associated with `file` variable?

Comment: ok, sounds stupid, but can we see htaccess? I had a friend who fixed cross-resource shizzle via htaccess

Comment: where do you define the javascript variable, `file`

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs not a stupid question! Will update ASAP :)

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi I realise I should've included that - one sec :'D

Comment: Start by checking what request your browser sends in the network panel … does that look like a proper file upload request to begin with?

Comment: @misorude `Request Method` is `Options` which is strange to me - but that could be normal.

Comment: @misorude never mind, just realised that there is an initial `Options` request and then another once the file is uploaded that is `POST`.

Comment: Tried `formData.append("track", file);`?

Comment: Yeah, using `withCredentials` should make this require a pre-flight request - which you need to handle accordingly. Your script needs to handle _both_ the OPTIONS request and the following POST request. And the OPTIONS request of course does not include the POST data.

Comment: Whoever is down voting my post; mind telling me why? I have ensured to include as much information that I think is necessary. I have shown that I have done research, and the post is formatted better than 95% of every other question on StackOverflow - what more do you want?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
> ```

The `Content-Type` header for a request formatted as `multipart/form-data` **must** include a `boundary` parameter to tell the recipient of the message where each new bit of data starts.

By manually providing the header without it, you make the request unparsable.

Remove that line. Allow XMLHttpRequest to generate the correct content-type header for you using the FormData object.

Comment: I've already done this, and it doesn't change the output in any way.